Ended Up With Weird SPL Token After SOL to USDC Swap
I swapped SOL to USDC on Phantom mobile wallet. Everything seems to happen fine. However, I am left with a USDC token that phantom does not show. Looking at the txn on SolScan, it is referred to as "SPL Token" with a caution symbol next to it. Any ideas? The token address is DkKY96SB6NPxLGWVigmWMhq7nxRaq7k1V7C54HFYEStr and when I looked, I can see a ton of transactions every minute or so, making it look like what one should expect for a token like USDC. Suffice to say I have no access the funds.

same here, what solution you do

You swapped a fake USDC instead of real USDC, Best is to swap it back to Real USDC before it gets rugged while there is still some liquidity. Always check the address before swapping.

Additionally: the official USDC address is published at circle.com
